# Rust library with exported C symbols and statically linked libstd

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-cargo

I have a small bit of wrapper C that sits between the Postgres API and my Rust code. I need to export those C functions so Postgres can call it.

I've tried both `dylib` and `cdylib` packages. `dylib` exports the symbols I expect:

```
$ nm target/release/libfdwtrait.so | grep add_one
0000000000005ef0 T add_one
0000000000005ee0 T pg_finfo_add_one
```

but it requires a libstd shared object:

```
$ ldd target/release/libfdwtrait.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x000000740050d000)
    libstd-6c11f2ad6c829596.so => not found
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x000000740049a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000007400350000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x00000074004e2000)
```

`cdylib` doesn't export the C functions I need:

```
$ nm target/release/libfdwtrait.so | grep add_one
zsh: done       nm ../target/release/libfdwtrait.so | 
zsh: exit 1     grep --color=auto add_one
```

but also doesn't require the shared object

```
$ ldd ../target/release/libfdwtrait.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x000000796a39b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x000000796a31c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x000000796a2f0000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x000000796a2ce000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x000000796a184000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x000000796a370000)
```

**src/fdw.c**:

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(add_one);

Datum
add_one(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
  int32   arg = PG_GETARG_INT32(0);
  int32   result = call_from_c(arg);

  PG_RETURN_INT32(result);
}
```

**src/lib.rs**:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn call_from_c(i: libc::int32_t) -> libc::int32_t {
    i * 2
}
```

I need some attributes of both `cdylib` and `dylib`. Unfortunately, they seem to be pretty hardcoded in the Cargo codebase.

Comment: I don't understand, be more clear. what is postgres API, why it's should call your c lib, and what your c lib is suppose to do with rust ? Also, keep in mind someone already work on it, https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres.

Comment: I mean the [c function api](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/xfunc-c.html). I don't want to query postgres, I want to write extensions.

Comment: in this case you don't need any wrapper you can directly do all in rust, and just use extern "C" in Rust. So postgres will just call your rust function. Take a look at https://bluejekyll.github.io/blog/rust/2018/12/27/announcing-pg-extend.html.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. The standard library isn't included *because you don't need it*. Multiplying a number by two is not a complicated operation.

Comment: *`nm target/release/libfdwtrait.so | grep add_one`* — your Rust symbol **isn't called `add_one`**. It's `call_from_c`.

Comment: You need to provide more information about why you think the Rust library should have the C objects in it. It's likely that you need to provide (1) the build script (2) the Cargo.toml (3) anything else needed to make this question have a [MCVE].